# Detect browser push notifications are enabled and display alert

Tags: javascript, push-notification, alert

I have enabled push-notifications for my website. When a user clicks a link on my site, a request will be send to the browser and the user have to click allow or disallow. Is there a way to detect if notifications are turned on and display an javascript alert box with the message that push notifications are successfully enabled? This may only display when the user allows notifications in his/her browser. Example:

> 1. The user clicks the link.
> 2. The user clicks allow in his/her browser.
> 3. There will be an alert with the message: "Successfully enabled"

Another example:

> 1. The user clicks the link.
> 2. The user clicks disallow in his/her browser.
> 3. There will be an alert with the message: "Error with enabling"

Does anyone understand me? If there are more questions, please write a comment, I'll add more info. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I mean the allow and disallow buttons that the browser asks. This are the buttons in a popup by the browser like this image: [https://www.igeeksblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Click-on-Allow-in-WhatsApp-Web-Notification-in-Chrome.jpg](https://www.igeeksblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Click-on-Allow-in-WhatsApp-Web-Notification-in-Chrome.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Notification.requestPermission()` is a Promise, that resolve with the permission chosen by the user.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission

```js
var myLink = document.getElementById("myLink");

myLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
   Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
      if (result === 'denied' || result === 'default' ) {
        alert("Error with enabling");
        return;
      }
      alert("Succesfully enabled");
    });
});
```

```html
<a id="myLink" href="#">Link</a>
```